# Creating different yet genuine human-sounding voices in Audacity. Is it Possible?

Tags: audacity, voice-manipulation

I would like to create a few voice characters for an animation in Audacity, editing  recordings of my own voice, however the final voices should sound completely different than my voice, and yet like genuine (unedited) human voices. Is that possible to achieve with Audacity?

Comment: no, no it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I can confidently say that what you are proposing is definitely not achievable with Audacity.